# Multiple services using a single instance of Arango DB

Tags: arangodb, arangodb-java

I am new to Arango DB. I am trying to achieve the following:

- Use a single Arango DB instance with multiple services.
- Keep the data separate for each service. I would like each service to handle its own data(query, collections, graphs, ...).

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to do this with ArangoDB java driver out of the box?
2. Would I need to create some kind of "middleware" service to do that?
3. Would there be a performance issue with this?

[image]

Comment: Running individual databases with fine grained user permissions does, what you need. Just create a database and different users for every application and there you go.

Comment: Can you explain it more? Do you have any links to Arango docs?